# Advanced Scrapy use Middleware

Tags: scrapy, middleware

I want to developt many middlewares to be sure websites'll be parse.
This is the workflow I thinks :

- First try with TOR + Polipo
- If 2 HTTP errors, try without TOR (so website know my IP)
- If 2 HTTP errors, try with proxy (use one of my other server to make HTTP REQ)
- If 2 HTTP errors, try with random proxy (on list of 100). This is repeat 5 times
- If none works, I save informations on ElasticSearch database, to see on my control panel

I'll create a custom middleware, with process_request function wich contains all of this 5 methods. But I don't find how save type of connection (for exemple if TOR not works, but direct connection yes, I want to use this settings for all of my other scrap, for the same website). How can I save this settings ?

Other thinks, I've a pipeline wich download images of items. Is there a solution to use this middleware (idealy with saving settings) to use on it ?

Thanks in advance for you're help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the [retry middleware](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py) as a starting point:

1. You could use `request.meta["proxy_method"]` to keep track of which one you are using
2. You could reuse `request.meta["retry_times"]` in order to track how many times you have retried a given method, and then set the value to zero when you change the proxy method.
3. You could use `request.meta["proxy"]` to use the proxy server you want via the existing HTTP proxy middleware. You may want to tweak the middlewares ordering so that the retry middleware runs before the proxy middleware.

Comment: Use `request` is only for ONE link, in my mind, I need to know wich method to use for all link on spider (each spider parse million of links). Perhaps with add custom variable on spider ?

Comment: @magexcustomer yes, if you need per-spider rules you have access to the spider instance in `process_request` and `process_response` methods.